# bootstrap 3 multi-level drop down menu item on mobile hide behind the parent

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, multi-level

I have a very strange problem with bootstrap 3 multi level menu on mobile. I have a drop down menu called extra +. Now on mobile when I click on extra then its submenu appears. But its hidden behind the other top level menu items. I tried z-index everywhere with media queries to address this issue, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Would you mind showing your code? It's hard to say anything not seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but resolved it with z-index...

```
.collapse, .navbar-collapse {
    z-index:9999;
}
```